# Insert POINT using CodeIgniter? (Prevent quotes from being added around POINT value?)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter to insert some data into a MySQL table. However, the single quotes automatically added in is giving me a problem with `'p' => 'POINT(1 1)'` because this causes the SQL query generated to be `'POINT(1,1)'` instead of `POINT(1,1)`. If i pass the `false` 2nd parameter, all the single quotes will be removed from the generated SQL query. How should I approach this problem?

**PHP Code**

```
$data = array(  'lat' => $url['lat'],
                'lng' => $url['lng'],
                'p' => 'POINT(1 1)'
                );
$this->db->insert('listings', $data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do something like

```
$this->db->set(array(
   'lat' => $url['lat'],
   'lng' => $url['lng'],
), true);
$this->db->set(array(
   'p' => 'POINT(1 1)'
), false);
$this->db->insert("listings");
```

The second parameter will make sure that the value isn't escaped.

Sorry if my answer is wrong, I am not using Codeigniter

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
$geo_cordinates = "GeomFromText('POINT(18.025600 72.251500)',0)"; 

$sql = "Insert into `tablename` (`geo_cordinates`) values ($geo_cordinates)";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

It's working for me. Hope will work for you also.